# Adding timeout to a dropdown menu not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, slidedown, slideup

I am working on a website and want to modify the current code for a dropdown menu item. Here is the current code:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 

$('#nav li').hover(
    function () {
        //show its submenu
        $('ul', this).slideDown(300);

    }, 
    function () {
        //hide its submenu
        $('ul', this).slideUp(300);         
    }
);

});
```

I tried changing the code to add a timeout with the intention of setting the timeout when the user took their mouse off of the menu so the menu didn't toggle the slide up effect right away. The desired effect that I want is that if the user takes their mouse off the menu for like 200 ms but then moves it back to the menu it doesn't do anything. So the menu waits like 300-400 ms to toggle the slide up function. Here is the code that I wrote that didn't work. Part of it was because of the `this` in `$('ul', this).slideUp(250);` Anyways, here is the code that I tried to implement that didn't work:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
var timeoutID;
$('#nav li').hover(
    function () {
        //show its submenu
        $('ul', this).slideDown(250);
        window.clearTimeout(timeoutID);
        timeoutID = window.setTimeout(SlideUp, 350);
    },  
);
function SlideUp() {
    //hide its submenu
    $('ul', this).slideUp(250);         
}
});
```

**What is the best way to have the program wait to toggle the slideup function?** Any ideas are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: [`jQuery.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) may help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you wanted to do.

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
  var timeout;
  $('#nav li').hover(function () {
    //show its submenu
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    $('ul', this).slideDown(300);
  }, function () {
    //hide its submenu
    var self = this;
    timeout = setTimeout(function(){
      $('ul', self).slideUp(300);         
    }, 300);
  });
});​
```

Comment: I tried implementing the code but it didn't work, but thanks for helping me understand the syntax better. I just ended up adding hoverIntent to the original code and it works ok.

Comment: yeah, for some reason it just didn't do anything when I put it in the code. It even disabled the dropdown which was weird cuz it looks like it would work. But changing the dropdown to add the timeout is such a minor detail that it can be overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

> jQuery.Deferred(), introduced in version 1.5, is a chainable utility
>   object that can register multiple callbacks into callback queues,
>   invoke callback queues, and relay the success or failure state of any
>   synchronous or asynchronous function.

Take a look at [this](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/).

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to your specific question, but I would use `transition-delay` if possible, [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Exj3w/1/).